# Show image in a div and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 20 boxes; the user can just select one of these.
**Now here's my problem.**
How can I do this? And if the user changes his selection, how would I automatically fadeout the previous choice using jQuery?

[image: my problem]

demo's here:
http://arta-web.ir/test/zoom-in.html

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main_div" style="width:800px; margin:auto">
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-1"><p>?</p><div class="tik untik"></div></div>
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-2"><p>?</p><div class="tik untik"></div></div>
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-3"><p>?</p><div class="tik untik"></div></div>
.
.
.
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-4"><p>?</p><div class="tik untik"></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .zoom-box {
  background: #7d7e7d;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#B7602F', endColorstr='red',GradientType=0);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#B7602F), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, yellow 0%,#B7602F 100%);
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, yellow 0%,#B7602F 100%);
  background:   -ms-linear-gradient(top, green 0%,#B7602F 100%);
  background:   -o-linear-gradient(top, green 0%,#B7602F 100%);
  background:     linear-gradient(top, green 0%,#B7602F 100%);
  width:147px;
  height:147px;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:right;
  margin:3px;
  border:solid 2px green;
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
    /*opacity:0*/
    cursor:pointer
}
.zoom-box p{font-size:150px; color:#fff; position:relative; top:-80px; right:30px; float:right}
.zoom-box div.tik{position:relative; z-index:5; width:124px; height:121px; background:url(tik.png) no-repeat; top:15px; right:-5px;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.tik').css('display','none');
    $('div.zoom-box').click(function() {
        $(this).children("div.tik").fadeToggle(200); // show untik" sign
        $(this).children("p").fadeToggle(200); // hide '?' sign
        $(this).children("div.tik").toggleClass('untik'); // showuntik" sign
        $(".tik .untik").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to hide everything but the one you clicked?

Comment: can you post a picture of how it should look before/after the click?

Comment: @ZachLeighton just show confirm sign in div wich clicked, no others!

Comment: @Banana dear, all div are '?'. when click on it appear '√';

Answer (score 0):

Just hide them before showing the clicked one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.tik').css('display','none');
    $('div.zoom-box').click(function() {
        $('div.zoom-box div.tik').addClass('untik') // I've added this line...
        $('div.zoom-box div.tik p').fadeOut(200) // ...and this.

        $(this).children("div.tik").fadeToggle(200); // show untik" sign
        $(this).children("p").fadeToggle(200); // hide '?' sign
        $(this).children("div.tik").toggleClass('untik'); // showuntik" sign
        $(".tik .untik").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could accomplish this is with less javascript and more CSS.

CSS3 transitions could be used for the fading effects...

```
.zoom-box .tik {
  opacity:0;  
  ....
}
.zoom-box.untik .tik {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

And then just use the javascript to toggle the classes and hide ones marked with a particular class:

```js
$('div.zoom-box').click(function() {
  // attach untik class
  $(this).toggleClass('untik'); 
  // show untik sign and fade out this one's untik'd siblings
  $(this).siblings('.untik').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.zoom-box {
  margin:0 10px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  font-size:2em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.zoom-box p {margin:0;padding:0;}
.zoom-box, .tik {
  background:orange;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center; 
  float:left;
}
.zoom-box .tik {
  opacity:0;  
  color:green;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.zoom-box.untik .tik {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div" style="width:800px; margin:auto">
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-1"><p>?</p><div class="tik">X</div></div>
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-2"><p>?</p><div class="tik">X</div></div>
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-3"><p>?</p><div class="tik">X</div></div>
  <div class="zoom-box" id="d-4"><p>?</p><div class="tik">X</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Larz but your code fade full boxe! i want just fade 'X' sign in others Div. thanks again

Comment: @M-O-H-S-E-N you didn't provide any CSS in your question above so this effect is from the css that I made up. If you're going to use it as a guide, just wrap the 'X' in a span or div, and then targeting that child element of the siblings you want to fade here `$(this).siblings('.untik').fadeOut();` I'm sure you already how to select the children of sibling elements :)

Comment: *I'm sure you already how to adjust this to select the children of sibling elements

Comment: im new in jquery. and my really first problem is! my language not english native, for this i cant good describe